# replace a library in perforce

Tags: version-control, perforce

I need to replace a library in a perforce depot. The library is checked in in the form of source files which are all managed by perforce.

Now the problem is that in the new version of the library there may be

- unchanged files
- changed files
- new files and
- some files may have been deleted

Of course I can just mark the whole source tree for delete, submit, copy the new version of the library to the directory in question, mark for add and submit again, but that would create a short interval of time in which no one should synchronize in order to not break his next build -- maybe that's the best option but I'd like to know whether there is a better approach.

A second solution is to copy the new version of the library to some other directory, update all references in order to reflect the new location, and then just delete the old library and mark the new one for add. This can be done in one change list. The unpleasant and error prone part here is to update the references. Also a change in the directory names is not really desired.

Does anyone know a way to do this in one step with one changelist? I experimented with a single file example. It actually *is* possible to mark a file for delete and then immediately create a file with the same name and mark that for add. If you do that and submit, then the result is exactly what I want for that single file. This procedure, however, seems to require touching each file manually. I could not figure out how to do that for a whole directory or directory tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to use `p4 reconcile` to do the majority of the work, using a process such as:

1. In your workspace, remove the current copy of the source tree entirely: `rm -rf top-directory-name` (or `del /s /q` if you're on Windows).
2. copy the entire new copy of the source tree for the library into that location.
3. Run `p4 reconcile` and let it figure out what files to open for add, for edit, and for delete. **CAREFULLY** inspect the results by looking closely at `p4 opened`, `p4 diff`, etc.
4. Submit the new changelist.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give this a try tomorrow. Is there a helix way of doing this?

Comment: If you mean P4V (Helix is just another name for Perforce), the equivalent to "reconcile" is "File > Reconcile".  You still need to copy the new files into your workspace.  Do *not* do a "remove from client"/"sync #none" beforehand; the reconcile command is going to compute the delta between what you had synced previously and what is now in your workspace, so you want your sync state ("have table") to reflect what you're modifying rather than an empty workspace.